# Android layout animations

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I want to implement a menu layout in android. The menu layout will be positioned at the bottom of the screen. I want to have a button that will be used to display and hide the menu layout. So far I have successfully implemented it as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/conversations_imageView_menu"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_olla_menu_conversations_show"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/conversations_menu_layout"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/conversations_menu_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_olla_block_user"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Block"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/conversations_menu_textColor"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_olla_group"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Groups"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/conversations_menu_textColor"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_olla_background"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Background"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/conversations_menu_textColor"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_olla_invite"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Invite"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/conversations_menu_textColor"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_olla_privacy"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Privacy"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/conversations_menu_textColor"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_olla_help"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Help"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/conversations_menu_textColor"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When a user clicks the `conversations_imageView_menu` ImageView, `conversations_menu_layout` layout will slide from the bottom and push the button up till all the content is visible. If the menu is visible, `conversations_menu_layout` will slide down and hide. Alternatively, I would like to display `conversations_menu_layout` using lollipop `circular reveal animations`. 
I have tried to implement the former and here are my animation files;

sliding up

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromYDelta="70%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

And sliding down

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="75%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

But the animation is not smooth. The button moves up, before the menu layout completes showing.How can I make it scroll smoothly downwards?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you :

```
Animation Animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.file);
v.startAnimation(Animation);
```

Here you can apply that animation to view v.